# List the files in a folder to ps -C as arguments

Tags: bash, ls, xargs

I would like to limit the process output of `ps` to a list of commands via the `ps -C` option.

e.g. `ps -C mycmd,mycmd2`or

`ps -C "mycmd mycmd2"` (here the double quotes are necessary, I think because of my `bash` want's this so)

So how can I set all the files I have in a folder as arguments to `ps -C` ?

`ls scripts |xargs ps -C` (doesnt work if multiple files are in scripts/. It runs `ps -C mycmd1 mycmd2` (without double quotes))

`ls scripts | xargs -I {} -t ps -C "{}"` (will issue the `ps -C` command for every file in scripts/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work

```
ls | paste -s -d, | xargs ps -C
```